# Yii 2.0 Advanced, Console Migration не работает

Tags: yii2, консоль, openserver, миграция

выдаёт следующее:

```
            d:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub>php yii migrate/create create_cities_table                                                                                     
            Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.17)                                                                                                                                 

            Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] ����������� �� �����������, �.�. �������� ��������� ������ ������ �� �����������.                       
            '                                                                                                                                                                         

            in D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php:624                                                                                   

            Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                              
            #0 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(996): yii\db\Connection->open()                                                       
            #1 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(983): yii\db\Connection->getMasterPdo()                                               
            #2 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(253): yii\db\Connection->getSlavePdo()                                                   
            #3 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(1153): yii\db\Command->prepare(true)                                                     
            #4 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(399): yii\db\Command->queryInternal('fetchAll', NULL)                                    
            #5 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\mysql\Schema.php(319): yii\db\Command->queryAll()                                                    
            #6 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\mysql\Schema.php(125): yii\db\mysql\Schema->findColumns(Object(yii\db\TableSchema))                  
            #7 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php(744): yii\db\mysql\Schema->loadTableSchema('migration')                                   
            #8 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php(194): yii\db\Schema->getTableMetadata('{{%migration}}', 'schema', true)                   
            #9 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\MigrateController.php(349): yii\db\Schema->getTableSchema('{{%migration}}', true)   
            #10 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController.php(631): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->getMigra
            tionNameLimit()                                                                                                                                                           
            #11 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionCreate('create_cities_t...')                                                                
            #12 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)                                          
            #13 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)                                  
            #14 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Controller.php(148): yii\base\Controller->runAction('create', Array)                           
            #15 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528): yii\console\Controller->runAction('create', Array)                               
            #16 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate/create', Array)                      
            #17 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(147): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate/create', Array)              
            #18 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))         
            #19 D:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\adrian_golub\yii(23): yii\base\Application->run()                                                                                       
            #20 {main}
```

Помогите разобраться.

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score -1):

Мдеа, решение оказалось почти пустяковое...

В файле main-local.php (configi к БД)

Было так:

```
<?php
        return [
            'components' => [
                'db' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
                    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=postgres',
                    'username' => 'postgres',
                    'password' => 'postgres',
                    'charset' => 'utf8',
                ],
                'mailer' => [
                    ...
                ],
            ],
        ];
```

а в строке надо было просто поменять "mysql" на "pgsql" :

```
    'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=postgres',
```